# How do I programmatically play a youtube video embedded with swfobject registerObject method?

Tags: swfobject, youtube-javascript-api

Does anyone have experience embedding flash with swfobject? Dynamic publishing worked as expected, but using their static publishing method, I couldn't control the player programmatically. Here's a description of what I tried

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Embed video using static publishing method from here: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation
2. use registerObject with a callback to capture the reference to the object
3. try to use any of the methods from the youtube api such as loadVideoById() or play() https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference
4. those methods are undefined in the object reference returned in the callback passed to registerObject

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**
these methods work if I use dynamic publishing
I was expecting to be able to use all of the methods listed here just as I can with the dynamic publishing method.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
2.2 mac osx firefox and chrome

Please provide any additional information below.

code snippets:

```
js:
swfobject.registerObject("myMovie0", "10", "", function(e){
    //try to do something with the player           
    e.ref.loadVideoById(videoID);
    e.ref.play();
});
```

html:

```
<object width="425" height="356" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"         id="myMovie0" style="visibility: visible;">
        <param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/_DofZYPYOxM?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;version=3" name="movie">
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object width="425" height="356" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/_DofZYPYOxM?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <!--<![endif]-->
          <p>You must have flash installed to see this video</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img alt="Get Adobe Flash player" src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif"></a></p>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

Thanks!